# Preparing a deck & playset for re-staining

Tags: wood, deck, staining

The question asked [here](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/what-are-the-proper-steps-for-staining-a-deck) is pretty much similar to mine except that there are few splinters and chipped wood on the deck. How to smooth those out? Also there is a kid's play structure (with steps and a border that hosts a slide, swings and monkey bars) in a similar staining need state, any special considerations for doing it?

Any good videos/links with the procedure, tools and product recommendations is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [answer](https://diy.stackexchange.com/questions/4972/what-are-the-proper-steps-for-staining-a-deck/4974#4974) given to the question you linked to, pretty much covers all you really need to know (IMHO).

> Q. There are few splinters and chipped wood on the deck. How to smooth those out?

Sanding by hand or with a random orbital sander should pretty much take care of those areas. If you need to smooth out *"really rough areas"*, go with something like:

- Begin with 60 Girt.
- Then move onto 100 Grit.
- Then finish with 150 Grit.

Though I'm guessing (not being able to see the actual state of your deck & playset) for most of your sanding needs, 100 & 150 Grits will be sufficient.